# corona simulator doesn't show full image

Tags: android, ios, lua, coronasdk

I'm creating simple game using corona.

First thing i'm trying to do is load the background image; but what i got is that, corona simulator show small part of image at the top most left side and the rest of image stay black even if i used all the scaling mode and i'm sure from image size.

Then i added three parameter to the `display.newimage` method so i got better situation but i still have a black bar on the left.

My `config.lua`

```
application = {
content = {
    fps = 60,
    width = 320,
    height = 480,
    scale = "zoomEven",
   -- xAlign = "center",
    --yAlign = "center",
    imageSuffix = {
        ["@2x"] = 2;
    },
},
}
```

and `main.lua`

```
local background = display.newImage("images/clouds.png");
```

first result on all devices 
[image]

then what i made to got better result is make this small edit to `main.lua`

```
local background = display.newImage("images/clouds.png",230,150, true);
```

and the second result 
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must modify the anchor property, this property allows you to control the alignment of the object along the x or y direction. By default, new objects have their anchor set to 0.5 corresponds to a center alignment. By setting it to 0 is meaning the left edge of the object.

```
local background = display.newImage("images/clouds.png");
background.anchorX = 0
background.anchorY = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

display.newImage() by default will want to draw the object at an X, Y of 0,0.  This represents the center of the object.  You can either change the anchor points as listed above.  You can provide an X, Y as parameters to display.newImage() or you can do:

```
local background = display.newImage("images/clouds.png");
background.x = display.contentCenterX
background.y = display.contentCenterY
```

I personally prefer this method because you explicitly position the item.

Rob